# How to use UI font icons inside an angular app

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, fonts, icons

I'm designing mockups in Sketch, and I'm using the home and search icons from a UI Font designed for icons. Now I want to display these icons in my angular app using html and css. There doesn't seem to be any resource online that teaches how to do this. I have used resources such as FontAwesome before which have very clear documentation on how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by copying the CSS attributes of the icon inside of sketch by right clicking:

```
/* home: */
font-family: UIFont-Solid;
font-size: 30px;
color: #FFFFFF;
```

So add this to your css:

```
.icon {font-family: UIFont-Solid; font-size: 30px; color: #FFFFFF;}
```

Then all you have to do in the html/view is add the class to the element and put the name of the icon as text inside of the element:

```
<div class="icon">home</div>
```

You can even put multiple icons in the same div:

```
<div class="icon">home search help</div>
```

Note that this may not work in production unless you add the font to the fonts folder and reference it in the css using @font-face.